# Is there a way to rebase a child branch after the parent has been rebased?

Tags: git

Assume I have the following scenario

```
       1->2->3 (continued-work)
      /           
  X->Y         (feature-branch)
 /
A->B->C->D     (master)
```

- "feature-branch" is currently out for CR and I'm addressing feedback
- "continued-work" is work I am building on top of "feature-branch" but I want to keep as a discrete set of work.

I am jumping back and forth between continued-work and feature-branch as I alternate between addressing code review feedback and building upon that work. After the work on feature-branch is signed off on, I want to squash those down into one commit ("Z"), rebase off of master and merge, so master looks like

```
A->B->C->D->Z     (master)
```

However doing so leaves continued-work in a bad place since I've messed with its ancestors and doing any sort of merge or rebase with it causes all sorts of merge conflicts. Is there a "right" way get from my starting scenario to

```
              1->2->3 (continued-work)
             /
A->B->C->D->Z         (master)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[git rebase --onto](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) is your answer.

When you squash your commits down, do it in a different branch.

1. `git checkout feature-branch`
2. `git checkout -b squashed-feat`
3. `git rebase <sha A> -i`

then rebase that on top of master

1. `git rebase master`

That will get you to you're 2nd last step as defined above:

```
A->B->C->D->Z     (master)
```

Then I would rebase the last commits with the following:

`git rebase --onto master feature-branch continued-work`

we do the first squashed rebase in a different branch to still have the nice branch reference to the `feature-branch`. Otherwise, we could still do it but just reference the sha-id of where the feature-branch was instead of the branch name `feature-branch`

Comment: *where the feature-branch was* – that can be referenced as `feature-branch@{1}`

Comment: Sounds reasonable, thanks! I'll give that a crack next time I get myself into this situation.

Comment: @mkrieger1, awesome! I always forget about reflog style references!